# How to add external js for tracking page to vue3?

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3

I’d like to connect third party code js to tracking a thank you page.

How to add external js for tracking page to vue3?

Comment: Dynamically create a `<script>` tag and append it to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can have to create `script` tag dynamically and append it to the `body` tag. Do not forget to set `async` and `defer` attributes to ensure those third-party scripts don't affect the performance

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute( 'src', src );
script.async = true;
script.defer = true;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```